# Print a data frame with columns aligned (as displayed in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, text-alignment, output-formatting

I have the following data frame in R:

```
> dframe
                Mean Median
Candidates     85.68     60
NonCands        9.21      4
Multi          27.48     17
Mono            4.43      3
Multi NonCands 22.23     15
```

I want to print it into a file and keep it nicely formatted and aligned just as shown above. I use:

```
write.table(dframe,file="test",sep="\t", quote=F)
```

which produces the following output:

```
Mean    Median
Candidates  85.68   60
NonCands    9.21    4
Multi   27.48   17
Mono    4.43    3
Multi NonCands  22.23   15
```

Since the data is displayed properly formatted within the R environment I thought it should be trivial to write it to a file with the same format. Apparently I was wrong. I have tried playing with `format()` and `write.matrix` from the MASS library but neither produces the desired result.

I have seen some suggestions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588266/1081936), but it seems both too complicated and, more importantly, does not produce the desired result when printing to a file with `write.table()`.

So, how can I print my data frame to a text file and have it look just as it does within R?

---

UPDATE

Following Justin's suggestion from his comment below, I installed the gdata library and used `write.fwf`. This is *almost* what I need:

```
write.fwf(dframe,file="test",sep="\t", quote=F, rownames=T)
```

produces the following output:

```
Mean    Median
Candidates      85.68   60
NonCands         9.21    4
Multi           27.48   17
Mono             4.43    3
Multi NonCands  22.23   15
```

So, any ideas on how to get "Mean" and "Median" shifted to the right so they align with their respective columns?

Since it may now be relevant, here is how the data.frame was created:

```
labels<-c("Candidates","NonCands","Multi", "Mono", "Multi NonCands")
Mean <- c(mean(cands), mean(non),mean(multi),mean(mono),mean(multi_non))
Median <- c(median(cands), median(non),median(multi),median(mono),median(multi_non))
names(Mean)<-labels
dframe<-data.frame(Mean,Median)
```

Comment: take a look at `write.fwf` from the `gdata` package.  `fwf` stands for fixed width file.  however, if the font used to view a text file isn't fixed width, it might not be even.

Comment: To be precise, you want the rownames left-aligned and padded, and the columns right-aligned. (`print.data.frame(... right=X)` only allows that option to be set globally, so a little tweaking needed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could redirect the output of `print` to file.

```
max.print <- getOption('max.print')
options(max.print=nrow(dframe) * ncol(dframe))
sink('dframe.txt')
dframe
sink()
options(max.print=max.print)
```

Comment: You may experience `getOption("max.print")` issue if the number of rows are greater than `max.print` value.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, please see my answer below, is there a way to get rid of row names/numbers in your simple solution?

Comment: @Sezen You could convert the data.frame to a matrix and set them all to the empty character.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use `capture.output` with `cat`

```
cat(capture.output(dframe), file = 'dframe.txt', sep = '\n')
```

Comment: `capture.output` takes a `file` parameter itself, too.

Answer (score 3):

To control the output, tune `print.data.frame` to your needs and capture the output to a file, eg.:

```
capture.output(
  print.data.frame(df, row.names=F, print.gap=3, quote=F, right=F),
  sep="\n", file="out.txt"
)
```

Comment: How does this print to a _file_?

Comment: It does not. I focused on the question of formatting the data frame.

Comment: Thanks, but the dataframe is displayed perfectly in R. The question is about printing it to a file, so your answer is not really relevant here.

Comment: Rewrote the answer completely

Comment: `sep="\n"` gives a "bad argument" error from `capture.output()` for me in R 4.0.2. Dropping it seems to give fine output.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Add the row names to the data frame, if you want them included
dframe2 <- data.frame("Row"=rownames(dframe), dframe, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# apply format over each column
dframe2 <- apply(dframe2, 2, format)

# print it out, make sure not to use quotes
write.table(dframe2, "test.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked the simplicity the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13591039/557884) of Matthew Plourde, but unfortunately, it does not offer a way to get rid of the row names/numbers for my situation; so, I modified a little bit the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13591329/557884) of Ricardo:

```
print.to.file <- function(df, filename) {
  cnames <- colnames(df)
  n      <- as.matrix(nchar(cnames))

  d <- apply(df, 2, format)
  n <- apply(cbind(n, nchar(d[1,])), 1, max)

  fmts <- paste0("%",n, "s")
  for(i in 1:length(cnames)) {
    cnames[i] <- sprintf(fmts[i], cnames[i])
    d[,i] <- sprintf(fmts[i], trimws(d[,i]))
  }
  d <- rbind(cnames, d)
  write.table(d, filename, quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=F)
}
```

This gives the same output of Matthew's except row names/numbers.

**EDIT:** replace `trim` with `trimws`.

Comment: Unfortunately in using the latest R... `Error in trim(d[, i]) : could not find function "trim"`

Answer (score 1):

Another way without row names based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13594659) of mnel:

```
prettyprint.df <- function(x, filename='dframe.txt', width=200)  
   # Pretty-print data frame without row names  
{  
   op.w <- options("width")  
   options("width"=width)  

   first <- max(nchar(rownames(x))) + 2  
   cat(substring(capture.output(x), first), file=filename, sep="\n")  

   options(op.w)  
}
```