# Saving a matrix to a .txt file with proper alignment

Tags: r, write.table

I am trying to save a matrix that I have in R as a text file that is tab-delimited with the row and column names included and properly aligned.

I have tried this:

```
write.table(data, "mytable.txt", sep="\t", col.names=TRUE)
```

But when I open the file it is a jumbled up mess. I assume it has something to do with my row or column names not being specified, but I am unsure.

Comment: I'm very new to R so I'm not even sure how the post @TimBiegeleisen listed helps me.  I understand they are both similar but I am still not able to solve my problem from that post.  I am also not sure how to redirect print() or what exactly that means.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code, which will write output of your matrix to file using the neat format you see when you print from the R console:

```
max.print <- getOption('max.print')
options(max.print=nrow(data) * ncol(data))
sink('data.txt')
data
sink()
options(max.print=max.print)
```

Look for an output file called `data.txt`.  To find the location, do `File -> Open script` from your R console.  It should be visible in the directory in which the dialog box opened.

**Disclaimer:** I basically cut-and-pasted this code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590887/print-a-data-frame-with-columns-aligned-as-displayed-in-r), of which your question is really a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

From `write.table` help page concerning CSV (also tab-separated) files:

> CSV files. By default there is no column name for a column of row
>   names. If col.names = NA and row.names = TRUE a blank column name is
>   added

Since `row.names = TRUE` is the default, if you change `col.names=TRUE` to `col.names=NA`, your output should be in the proper alignment.