# Printing out R Dataframe - Single Character Between Columns While Maintaining Alignment (Variable Spacing)

Tags: r

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492720/outputting-an-r-dataframe-to-a-txt-file-align-positive-and-negative-values), I received output for an R dataframe that had two aligned columns. The answer gave me the following output:

[image: Dataframe output - columns separated by variable number of space characters]

While the post answered my initial question, it seems as if the [program I intend to use](http://pantherdb.org/geneListAnalysis.do) requires a text file in which the two columns are both aligned and separated by a single character (e.g. a tab). The previous solution instead results in a large and variable number of spaces between the first and second columns (depending on the length of the string in the first column for that particular row.) Inserting a single character, however, results in a misalignment of the columns.

Is there any way in which I can replace a large number of spaces with a single character that has variable spacing to 'reach' to the second column?

If it helps, [this webpage](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41596-019-0128-8/MediaObjects/41596_2019_128_MOESM4_ESM.txt) contains a .txt file that you may download to see the intended output (although it does not suffer from the problem with the first column having variable name lengths, it has a single 'space character' that separates the first and second columns. If I 'copy and paste' this specific space character between columns 1 and 2, the program can successfully interpret the .txt file. This copy + paste results in a single character separating the columns and appropriate alignment.)

For further example, the first of the following pictures (note the highlight is a single character) properly parses while the second does not:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a regular expression task `gsub("\\s+", "\t", x)` or something like that to replace any number of consecutive spaces with a tab.

Comment: @thelatemail this unfortuantely did not work. It instead printed two rows of data with the first row reading `c("CHEK2 ", "MYL2 ",...` and the second row reading `c("-2.869351", "-2.477345", "-2.473197",...`