# Windows: Print to printer from R - quick and dirty is OK

Tags: r

On a Windows PC, how can I quickly print a data.frame to a printer?  It doesn't have to be pretty; just trying to get it printed out for documentation purposes.

I'm aware of this SO question [How to print (to paper) a nicely-formatted data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587621/how-to-print-to-paper-a-nicely-formatted-data-frame) and answers but I'm really looking for something that just prints out the text

Comment: Copy/paste it into notepad and print that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a bit of code that I use all the time:

```
print_to_printer <-function(df, addquotes = FALSE){     
write.csv(df, "c:\\PRINT_ME.txt", quote = addquotes)
shell("NOTEPAD /P c:\\PRINT_ME.txt")   
cat(quote(df), " has been printed to printer")}
```

then you can use it with

```
print_to_printer(my_df)
```

if your data.frame is called my_df.  Your can change the printed quotes on or off, as needed.

I have to give credit to Alin Constantin for helping me to derive the solution in R:   http://alinconstantin.blogspot.com/2012/08/notepadexe-command-line-arguments.html