# Is it possibly to print (to a physical printer) from a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I know how to create a pdf or png from a displayed plot in shiny and make it available for download (if the user clicks on a button, for instance), but is it possible to send it to a - physical - printer? I.e. the user clicks on a button and the standard Print dialog comes in, after selecting the printer, the plot is sent - instead of a pdf or png - to the printer.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/33047488/5784831

Comment: @Christoph Thanks! Apart from the fact that I don't know how `shell` would work through shiny, it is only solution for something that can be - meaningfully - sent to `notepad.exe`, so not a figure (plot) that I'd need...

Comment: Perhaps save the picture as e.g. png. Then use shell command from r to send it to the printer. If you Need more help a reproducible example would help.

Comment: My problem with this shell command approach is that everything I run as a shell command in shiny will be run _on the server_ (as far as I know), so even if it works, it would print on the server's printer...