# Plotting a Data Frame (no grid.table)

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, package, gridextra

The question of today is pretty simple. I need to plot a Data frame so it shows in the plot viewer in R studio.

I read this Q&A already:

[How to print (to paper) a nicely-formatted data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587621/how-to-print-to-paper-a-nicely-formatted-data-frame)

Where they are advising to use grid.table from GridExtra package.

The thing is that im having problem with this package as is overlapping my other plots I dont know why?

Maybe you know any other functions or package that can do the same without overlapping my other plots!

This is what I mean by overlapping.

```
> date_alert
          Jobs    Agency Location       Date RXH HS TMM Payed
1  Playstation Lightblue     DWTC 2015-09-24  90  8 720 FALSE
2 RWC Heineken Lightblue      EGC 2015-09-26  90  6 540 FALSE
3 Jagermeister       IHC  Barasti 2015-10-01 100  4 400 FALSE


> library(gridExtra)
> grid.table(date_alert)
```

[image]

It does that all the time! no matter how many times I restart all the script and R studio.

Thanks

Comment: The documentation demonstrates the use of `library(grid); grid.newpage()`.

Comment: Thanks! that sorted it out!

Comment: @Roland post as an answer?

Comment: @baptiste Your wish is my command. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot a grid grob to a new page you need to create a new page first. The example in `help("grid.table")` demonstrates how to do that:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
```

Note that many higher level grid-based plotting functions, such as `ggplot2:::print.ggplot` call `grid.newpage` internally. But `grid.table` doesn't since the common use case is adding a table to a plot. There are better possibilities if your goal is exporting just a table.